# How to delete Databricks feature tables through the Python API

Tags: python, databricks, feature-store

The documentation explains how to [delete feature tables through the UI](https://docs.databricks.com/applications/machine-learning/feature-store/ui.html#delete-a-feature-table).

Is it possible to do the same using the Python *FeatureStoreClient*? I cannot find anything in the docs: https://docs.databricks.com/_static/documents/feature-store-python-api-reference-0-3-7.pdf

Use case: we use ephemeral dev environments for development and we have automated deletion of resources when the environment is torn down. Now we are considering using the feature store, but we don't know how to automate deletion.

Answer (score 1):

You can delete a feature table using the Feature Store Python API.
It is described here:
http://docs.databricks.com.s3-website-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/applications/machine-learning/feature-store/feature-tables.html#delete-a-feature-table

Use drop_table to delete a feature table. When you delete a table with drop_table, the underlying Delta table is also dropped.

```
fs.drop_table(
  name='recommender_system.customer_features'
)
```

Comment: Note that this requires DBR 10.5+

Answer (score 1):

The answer above is correct, but note that the `drop_table()` function is experimental according to databricks documentation for the [Feature Store Client API](https://docs.databricks.com/_extras/documents/feature-store-python-api-reference-0-8-0.pdf) so it could be removed at any time. Besides that `fs` is also in reference to:

```py
from databricks.feature_store import FeatureStoreClient
fs = FeatureStoreClient()

fs.drop_table(name='recommender_system.customer_features')
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33459819)

Comment: I upvoted since it is relevant: however, It is not working for me - and on the precise table that you show in the example.  The table is not apparently dropped